# Display searchresults

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to know how to display searchresults using the standard driveinterface.

```
function getSearchResults(searchText)
{
  // SearchText contains a info about fulltext, title, modifieddate and parents 
  var filesFound = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchText);

  //   ... Now display filesFound in the driveinterface (if possible)
  //   or in a similar way (how ?)
}
```

Is it possible to actually use the standardintreface for displaying filesFound , either directly or by creating a folder and displaying that folder? (how??)

Or will it be necessary to creat a form, create your own interface etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to embed the Drive application directly into your UI. You'll need to create your own interface or give the user a link to the Drive directly.

Comment: So this means it will take a lot of time to display results if a large number of hits occur. Creating my own interface is not tempting. Do you know of code for such a trivial thing as displaying files? What do you mean by 'give the user a link to the Drive directly'?

Comment: I don't know of any existing code to do this. You can create a link to Google Drive search results like this: https://drive.google.com/#search/foobar

Comment: Yes, but that implies that the search query must be send as well. I would like the user to select a few (but not all) directories and some texts and maybe within a certain period (last week or last month). Currently it's possible to do it (for me) in GAS (based on http://eatenbyagrue.org/the_google_drive_api_doesnt_know_about_paths_and_thats_bad.html), but not creating a searchstring that provides the same result.